# c++11 initializer list as an array

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have the following function

```
void f(double* arr) 
{ ... }
```

Is this a sensible way to call that function in C++11: `f({10.0, 8.0});`? Thanks.

Comment: What did your [compiler tell you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d229137bd3567fa0) when you tried it?

Comment: sorry. I had a function with overloading where that worked, with one of the overloads

Comment: @hovo as a general rule, generate [MCVE]s before posting to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make a small wrapper around the `f`  function:

```
void f(double* arr){

}
void f_wrapper(std::vector<double> v){
    f(v.data());    
}
int main(){
  f_wrapper({1.,2.,3.});
}
```

or as @(Kerrek SB) mentioned:

```
void f(const double* arr){

}

void f_wrapper(std::initializer_list<double> v){
    f(v.begin());
}

int main(){
   f_wrapper({1.,2.,3.});
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::initializer_list<double>`?

Comment: Possible but you need to make a const overload of the f function